# Samsumg WEP470 bluetooth headset won't work in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, headset

I'm trying to use my Samsung WEP470 bluetooth headset with Windows 7 for VOIP apps.  When I try to "Add a Bluetooth Device" in the control panel, it detects the headset and installs a driver.  However, at the end of driver installation, I see the error message, "This device cannot start. (Code 10)"

I've deleted the WEP470 profile and uninstalled the driver several times. Every time I try to pair it again, the profile is created and Windows 7 starts installing the driver, but fails at the end with the Code 10 error.

I'm using the Microsoft Bluetooth transceiver that came with my Microsoft IntelliMouse Explorer for Bluetooth, and the mouse works fine.

From other Superuser.com posts, it looks like the headset should just work, as long as I have the Bluetooth transceiver's drivers properly installed.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem: my old Microsoft Bluetooth adapter apparently didn't support the version of the Bluetooth spec required by the headset.  I bought a $2 USB Bluetooth dongle from Meritline.com.  I plugged it into my computer and Windows 7 installed some drivers automatically.  Then I paired the headset again, and now the Bluetooth headset works in Windows 7!

Answer (score 0):

have you downloaded and installed the Microsoft bluetooth stack if so you may need to update your bluetooth profiles for your bluetooth module

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but as far as I know, blutetooth has been included in Windows since WinXP SP2.  I've tried deleting the profile and pairing the headset again several times, but the Device Manager always says the driver cannot start.