# Why a bluetooth headset for mobile phones doesn't work on a PC?

Tags: bluetooth, mobile-phone, headset

Why a bluetooth headset like [this one](http://www.alibaba.com/product-gs/215692669/Bluetooth_headset_N95.html), which works well on a cell phone, doesn't work on a computer?

I can pair the headset with my laptop with no problems. And it's even recognized as an audio device in the list of bluetooth devices. However the device doesn't show up as an audio device in Windows' control panel.

I've tried with different PCs. Several laptop and desktop computers, with different version of Windows and each time the same thing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stock Bluetooth stack from Microsoft does not support using a Bluetooth headset as a generic audio device. Get the Bluetooth stack provided by the dongle vendor.

Comment: I've used several headsets with Microsoft's Bluetooth stack in Windows 7. The only time I had trouble was when I was using an older Bluetooth transceiver. See http://superuser.com/questions/119707/samsumg-wep470-bluetooth-headset-wont-work-in-windows-7

Comment: Maybe Windows 7 changed it. I haven't had a chance to look at Bluetooth under Windows 7.