# Why can't I use my Bluetooth Headset with my laptop?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, bluetooth, headset

I just received a new [Plantronics M50](http://www.plantronics.com/us/product/m50) bluetooth headset. It works great with my phone, but I can't get it working with my laptop.

What are the things I should be checking?

Here's what I've done so far:

- It pairs successfully: [image: it pairs]
- It's not in multipoint mode--it's only paired to my laptop
- <del>I've installed all available drivers from Plantronics and Dell</del> -- **the accepted answer documents how another was discovered, which resolved my issue**
- I have no (!) in Device Manager (though I don't see the headset there either--would I?)
- I can "configure" the headset by double clicking on it:
- "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" is unchecked in the Bluetooth radio settings
- Apps that let me choose the playback/mic device only list my laptop, not the headset
- I went into the Bluetooth device's properties and Checked "headset" under the services tab. This was successful but hasn't delivered any functionality as far as I can tell

I'd like to use this headset for VOIP conferencing (Goto meeting, Gmail voice chat, G+ hangouts, Skype, etc.) and listening to music (iTunes).

**Where else should I be digging?**

Is it possible that this new headset is simply not compatible with computers (i.e. it's only compatible with phones)?

Comment: Is the device seen in the audio/microphone settings panel?

Comment: @ThiagoM if you mean [this page](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/The-Playback-Tab-on-the-Sound-Window-in-Windows-7_thumb.png), then no. (that's not me, just an example)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why a bluetooth headset for mobile phones doesn't work on a PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/181654/why-a-bluetooth-headset-for-mobile-phones-doesnt-work-on-a-pc)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The MS-supplied Bluetooth drivers don't support HSP/A2DP as a soundcard. Use the drivers that came with your dongle/device.

If your laptop manufacturer doesn't list any drivers, do this:

1. Open device manager
2. Open the properties for "generic bluetooth radio"
3. Copy the "Hardware ID" into Google and do a search (but don't download anything yet!)
4. This should tell you what the device is called, e.g. "Dell Wireless 375 Bluetooth Module"
5. Unless you're already on a reputable site, do a second Google search for the device's name, e.g. "Dell Wireless 375 Bluetooth Module driver download"
6. Download and install the driver from a reputable site (e.g. Dell)
7. After it's installed, go open the device you already paired and you should see better options

Comment: Run the executable that installs the driver.

Comment: I did that. I installed everything dell has for my laptop and the device maker (plantronics) has. It pairs now but no further...

Comment: Then try the website of the Bluetooth device manufacturer itself.

Comment: What are the IDs of the Bluetooth device?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3078/discussion-between-michael-haren-and-ignacio-vazquez-abrams)

Comment: Worked for me.. Had the exact same issue on a Lenovo T440 with a Sony headset... The new drivers automatically detected and added it as a playback device.

Comment: Similar issue with HP EliteBook 8570p. Similar solution (downloaded updated version of broadcom bluetooth drivers). However, also had to reboot and uninstall / reinstall bluetooth device as well as go to the device's properties/hardware tab/check off all options listed there. Wait for drivers to install, turn device off then on again.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with a pair of MPOW T5 wireless earbuds. After the drivers installed for mine I still had a "Bluetooth Peripheral Device" as an unknown device with missing driver.  I followed the steps on [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/547979/bluetooth-headset-drivers-on-windows-7) to resolve that.

After that, Windows showed my Bluetooth headset listed on the playback devices and recording devices tabs, but it still wouldn't connect to them.  Starting from the System Tray, I had to open Bluetooth devices, open Services and enable the device for use as headphones and mic (see screenshot)

[image: enable Bluetooth device services in Windows 7]

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, different Bluetooth profiles exist for mobile phones and computers. Computers have Bluetooth technology for sharing data. Mobile phones have Bluetooth technology for communicating voice. Both are Bluetooth but are not able to connect as you would think.

The M50 specs read:

> Bluetooth Profiles: Advanced Audio Distribution Profile (A2DP), Hands-Free (HFP) Profile 1.6 and Headset (HSP) Profile 1.2

So, with the M50 you can only use to pair with a mobile phone and a computer is simply not compatible. To solve your issue, a different headset like the Plantronics Voyager Pro B230 will pair to your mobile phone and also comes with a USB dongle that plugs into your PC for computer use. One headset to connect to two devices, via voice and data.

Comment: This simply is not true...

This depends on your bluetooth radio hardware/adapter on your computer/laptop and whether it supports the audio/headset profile that the blue tooth headset is using. It has little / nothing to do with the bluetooth accessory itself.

Answer (score 0):

Check your sound settings also.  My M50 also paired under Windows 7 but I didn't hear anything.  I went to Sound in Control Panel and set my M50 as the default sound device and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a Dell Latitude E7440-and Platronics M50. I installed the drivers from Intel 
https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25208/Intel-PROSet-Wireless-Software-for-Bluetooth-technology-for-Windows-7-64-bit-JP-

reboot the pc. 
remove my bluetooth 
re add it - devicemanager - add bluetooth device make sure the headset profile is selected for the device. 
then go to the speaker icon in systray and look at playback devices

i see both blue tooth devices

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you got it working, but I also wanted to suggest trying a different Bluetooth transceiver. I had a [similar problem](https://superuser.com/questions/119707/samsumg-wep470-bluetooth-headset-wont-work-in-windows-7) in the past where my Bluetooth headset would pair but wouldn't actually work as an audio device. When I replaced the computer's Bluetooth adapter with a different one, it worked fine under Windows 7 using Microsoft's stock Bluetooth drivers.