# Bluetooth headset drivers on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio, bluetooth, headset

I have a Dell Precision with integrated Bluetooth from work. I wanted to connect either one of my two Bluetooth headsets (Plantronics UC Voyager Pro v2 and Sennheiser MM450X) in order to make calls with it using our Cisco IP Communicator.

In both cases, the Bluetooth device pairs OK. Then Windows tries to install drivers, and fails, leaving the device useless. The devices work perfectly with my phone and tablet (both Android).

What can I do to get it to work? I can't seem to find drivers on either the Plantronics or the Sennheiser site. I am using the Plantronics without the USB dongle they provide, because that is temporarily misplaced :).

Comment: Its very likely the USB dongle would install the required drivers.

Comment: Ok, that might be. But imagine I don't have the Plantronics headset, and only the Sennheiser. That should also work.

Answer (score 4):

These are the steps that helped me in a similar situation:

1. Remove all device drivers that you already tried installing to fix this issue
2. Reboot
3. Install the Broadcom Driver 6.2.1.500
4. Pair the headset device with the computer
5. In the device manager, check whether there is a single "Bluetooth Periphal Device" listed with missing driver, if so, continue with the next steps
6. Right click on the device, select "Update Driver Software...", then "Browse my computer [...]", followed by "Let me pick from a list [...]"
7. In the list of hardware types, choose "Ports (COM & LPT)" (!)
8. In the following window, select manufacturer "Microsoft" and model "Standard Serial over Bluetooth link", then click "Next"
9. A driver update warning will probably pop up, click "Yes"

This is in short the list of steps described by Andy Dendifer in the [Windows Forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/error-bluetooth-peripheral-device-driver-not-found/5509713a-0ab7-4c27-9a39-90acf5c0a454?page=2&auth=1). Look there for a much more detailed explanation, it's a humorful read.

Answer (score 1):

Driver update:

http://www.plantronics.com/us/support/myheadset/updater/

Software download:

http://www.plantronics.com/us/support/software-downloads/

http://www.plantronics.com/us/support/myheadset/

http://www.plantronics.com/us/support/software-downloads/software-archive/index.jsp

[User Manuals Voyager pro uc](http://www.plantronics.com/us/product/voyager-pro-uc)

[Compatibility Center: Plantronics Voyager PRO UC Wireless Bluetooth Headset](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/win7/CompatCenter/ProductDetailsViewer?Type=Hardware&Name=Plantronics%20Voyager%20PRO%20UC%20Wireless%20Bluetooth%20Headset&Vendor=Plantronics&ModelOrVersion=38667-01&Locale=1033&BreadcrumbPath=plantronics%20voyager%20pro&tempOsid=win7)

[ActiveSync 4.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15)

[Microsoft Windows Mobile Device Center 6.1 Driver for Windows Vista (64-bit)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3182)

Dell/HP/ect Laptop Inbuilt Stack:

[Software Support for HP Integrated Module with Bluetooth Wireless Technology for Microsoft Windows 7](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&tmp_geoLoc=true&softwareitem=ob-76382-1)

Dell stack only not found ...

Get device at Bluetooth tools and stack - Intel, Toshiba, Broadcom ...

Comment: I think the Plantronics links target their desktop headsets (the ones that use USB connection), not their Bluetooth headsets.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting my solution.

The problem was: couldn't connect my **bluetooth handsfree QY7S** on **windows 7** 64bit on laptop **Fujitsu T902** (refurbised).

I paired the handsfree. Windows Update couldn't find something that worked. Tried manually with drivers that were inside the system already. From this site https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/647512/how-to-fix-bluetooth-peripheral-device-driver-not-found-error-in-windows-7/ I found this link https://www.driverscape.com/download/windows-mobile-based-device-support from where I just were continuously trying different drivers. The one that worked were the *version 4.0.0.302* !!!
 Then, it install a lot from windows update, restarted, and this time it finally worked. From bluetooth /connected devices + right click I could now find the option "operation for experienced users", where I could connect to my handsfree finally! The option "Services" was available before, but the links that had were not working.
 I don't know if here is the proper place to write all these. It is my first post, so be kind :) I was super happy to finally solve this problem, took me many hours..! And wanted to share ✌️